# find and remove unused files and folders from solution and from disk in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I try to clean up our application. We use Visual Studio Community 2019. There you have the advantage that you can create solution folders which may not correspond to physical folders. But this is also a problem. It is difficult to find correspondence between what's in solution and what's on disk. The VS solution has grown huge and consists of more than 100 projects and there are piled up things not used anymore, not to mention folders on disk with various files not used (anymore) in the solution. In order to clean up the application, I need to know what's not used, I need to find which files and folders and even projects are not used anymore in our solution. I want to delete everything on disk which we don't need and also to remove the unused stuff from solution. So:

- is it any way to get a list/report with correspondence between what's in solution and where is on disk?
- is it any way to get a list/report with what is used (or what is unused) in solution/projects so I can delete from disk what's not used?

As a note, for whatever matters, it's a C# MVC application.
10x

Comment: Anything that is needed would be re-created on a **rebuild** of the sln. Perhaps create a duplicate to test this out so as not to delete anything permanently.

Comment: In the "SolutionExplorer" pane, if you select "Show All Files" for a project, then the virtual filters are removed and the on-disk structure is shown.

Comment: @silvlu, I suggest that you can try to use visual studio extension to find unused files. Please find 'FindUnusedFiles' in the visual studio market place and install it.